# Find the name of the most recent file with specific extension from a directory elegantly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to read the contents of a directory and find the most recent file name of files with a specific extension. This is my first trial:

```
def mostrecent_fn(dirname, extension):
   punsrtd = [ 
      os.path.join(dirname, fn) 
         for fn in os.listdir(dirname) 
            if fn.endswith(extension) 
               and os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dirname, fn))
   ]

   psorted  = sorted(punsrtd, key=os.path.getmtime)
   fname    = psorted.pop()         # last element = latest date
   path_fn  = os.path.split(fname)  # remove path again
   return path_fn[1]                # and return
```

This works when called like (in Windows):

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

[...]

dn = r'C:\Temp\Some\Dir\With\Data' 
fn = mostrecent_fn(dn, '.dat')
```

But if you look at the subroutine, it doesn't look very much like Python. It looks more like Perl.

What would be the elegant, performant (maybe up to 10,000 files) and 'pythonic' way to express this?

Answer (score 1):

*What would be the elegant*

This

```
   psorted  = sorted(punsrtd, key=os.path.getmtime)
   fname    = psorted.pop()         # last element = latest date
```

might be replaced with one line

```
fname = max(punsrtd, key=os.path.getmtime)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [pathlib module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```py
from pathlib import Path

def get_mtime(path):
    return path.stat().st_mtime

extension = '.dat'
start_dir = 'path/to/my/folder'
files = Path(start_dir).glob('*' + extension)
newest = sorted(files, key=get_mtime).pop()
```

It's pythonic and `glob` supports recursive searches by prepending `**/` to the pattern but that won't be fast.

Comment: Are you sure `sorted(files, key=get_mtime, reverse=True).pop()` provides newest file?

Comment: Good catch, I accidentally reversed the order. Fixed now.